# Импортировать необходимые хендлеры для работы в другом файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, aiogram

Есть файл `main.py` и необходимо сделать так, чтобы всё могло обрабатываться через хендлеры в другом файле `handlers.py`:

Файл `main.py`:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from config import telegram_bot_token

botSender = Bot(token=telegram_bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(botSender)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Файл в котором должна обработаться команда `/start` ( `handers.py`):

```
from main import dp
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command

@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
async def hhd(message: types.Message):
    print(message.text)
```

> Если поместить декоратор с функцией в главный файл всё работает на отлично, а так не работает, в чём проблема?

Comment: попробуйте вот так dp = Dispatcher(Bot(token=telegram_bot_token)). Работает?

Comment: нет, так не работает